# Is there a way to get a value of a property by an expression that holds its name in MsBuild?

Tags: msbuild

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Values Include="*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <Name>Values</Name>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="DisplayContent">

    <!-- works in a traditional way: -->
    <Message Text="@(Values)" />

    <!-- wish could do something like this: -->
    <Message Text="@($(Name))" />
</Target>
```

Is there a way to get a value of a list/property by utilizing its name held by a string expression in MSBuild?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are really trying to accomplish.  This sounds like a good use of MSBuild conditions.

Comment: I have a variable `A` that holds the value `"B"` of the type `string`. There is also a list named `B`. Now I want to use the value of variable `A` in order to get what's in the list `B` thank to the fact that the value of `A` (string `"B"`) **is** the name of the list `B`.

Comment: You have done a good job explaining the exact steps you want to take down a path that doesn't exist.  I am trying to understand your goal so that we can find a different path to reach your destination.  See my proposed answer for one approach.

Comment: What version of msbuild you are using? This works perfectly in MsBuild 12 (@MarkArnott as well) Also there's a `"` missing in your code sample after `DisplayContent`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use your $(Name) variable as a condition to import a specific ItemGroup.  You could do that like this:

```
<Import Project="ListA.prop" Condition="$(Name) == 'A'" />
<Import Project="ListB.prop" Condition="$(Name) == 'B'" />

<Message Text="@(Values)" />
```

Then you have ListA.prop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
  <Values Include="A1;A2;A3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And for ListB.prop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
  <Values Include="B1;B2;B3" />
</ItemGroup>
```

So instead of having multiple lists with different names you only load the list you want using a condition based on your variable.